# LINQ retrieve values from a table that of which fields(of a certain column) are not equal of another table

Tags: linq

I have two tables which have a column in common, how can I retrieve the first table where the values of it's column are not equal to the values of the column of the other table?

Here is an example:

```
  table1ID | foo    | fooBool        table2ID | foo      | fooin
 ----------------------------        -----------------------------

     1    |  test1  | true              1     |   test2  |    5
     2    |  test2  | true              2     |   test3  |    7
     3    |  test3  | true
     4    |  test4  | false
```

Therefore the result of the LINQ query for the first table that has values of foo not equal that of table2 are:

```
table1ID | foo    | fooBool
---------------------------    
   1     | test1  | true
   4     | test4  | false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var results = from t1 in db.table1
              from t2 in db.table2
              where t1.foo != t2.foo
              select t1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the [`Intersect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) IEnumerable Extension

```
var results = db.table1.Intersect(db.table2);
```

Or in LINQ

```
var codes = from intersected in db.table1.Intersect(db.table2)
            select intersected.foo;
```

This would produce

```
 results 
 ----------
 test2
 test3
```

**Update**

Thanks to Joe for pointing out that `Intersect` would produce the common items (added sample above).  What you would want is the [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) extension method.

```
var results = db.table1.Except(db.table2);
```

Or in LINQ

```
var codes = from diff in db.table1.Except(db.table2)
            select diff.foo;
```

This would produce

```
 results 
 ----------
 test1
 test4
```

Comment: The intersect operator produces the set intersect of two sequences. This is the opposite of what the OP is trying to achieve. The Except operator would be the appropriate one here.

Comment: AFAIK, yes, although you may be able to write something using the IEqualityComparer.  You could also write your own Generic Extension method that accepts a Predicate<T> for comparison.